# Php multi array foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays

i would like to find the country iso code in this array:

```
$countryArray = array(
        'AD' => array(
        'country_name' => 'ANDORRA',
        'dial_code' => '376'
        ),
        'AE' => array(
        'country_name' => 'UNITED ARAB EMIRATES',
        'dial_code' => '971'
        ),
        'AF' => array(
        'country_name' => 'AFGHANISTAN',
        'dial_code' => '93'
        ));
```

my condition is:

```
foreach($countryArray as $row){
    if($row->dial_code == '93'){
        echo $row; //???
    }
}
```

in the echo statement, i would like to display AF in this example.
but the result is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it , below code work fine

```
$countryArray = array(
        'AD' => array(
        'country_name' => 'ANDORRA',
        'dial_code' => '376'
        ),
        'AE' => array(
        'country_name' => 'UNITED ARAB EMIRATES',
        'dial_code' => '971'
        ),
        'AF' => array(
        'country_name' => 'AFGHANISTAN',
        'dial_code' => '93'
        ));

foreach ($countryArray as $keys=> $arraycountry){
    foreach($arraycountry as $key => $value)
    {
        if($value == '93'){
            echo $keys; //???
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`foreach($countryArray as $key => $row){
    if($row['dial_code'] == 93){
        echo $key; //???
    }
}`

try this one, just use `$key` variable inside your foreach loop

Answer (score 2):

`$key=>$value` pair in foreach statement assign current key element to $key and current value to $value .As we know foreach statement works on internal pointer.

```
$countryArray = array(
    'AD' => array(
    'country_name' => 'ANDORRA',
    'dial_code' => '376'
    ),
    'AE' => array(
    'country_name' => 'UNITED ARAB EMIRATES',
    'dial_code' => '971'
    ),
    'AF' => array(
    'country_name' => 'AFGHANISTAN',
    'dial_code' => '93'
    ));
foreach($countryArray as $key =>$value){
if($value['dial_code'] == 93){
    echo $key;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
foreach($countryArray as $k => $row){
    if($row["dial_code"] == 93){
        echo $k;
    }
}
```