# Sort array matching key order

Tags: php, sorting

I have the following arrays:

```
$names = array('fred', 'bob', 'john');

$input = array('bob' => array('bob data'), 'john' => array('john data'), 'fred' => array('fred data'));
```

I want to re-order the keys in `$input` so that they are in the exact same order as specified in `$names`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing how the second array is already suitably indexed, you can treat this as a recombination problem rather than thinking in terms of sorting algorithms:

```
function recombine(array $input, array $names)
{
    $result = [];
    foreach ($names as $name) {
        $result[$name] = $input[$name];
    }
    return $result;
}

$input = recombine($input, $names);
```

If some names are not present in `$input` you need to put a condition inside the loop body.

Comment: sometimes it takes someone else to look at your code to make you realise the obvious! thanks and I have downvoted that idiot who stole your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
function sortByArray($input, $order)
{
    $sorted = array();
    $count = count($order);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        if (isset($input[$order[$i]])) {
            $sorted[$order[$i]] = $input[$order[$i]];
        }
    }
    return $sorted;
}

$input = sortByArray($input, $names);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$names = array('fred', 'bob', 'john');
foreach($names as $val){
    $input[$val]=array($val=>$val."Data");
}
var_dump($input);
```

Answer (score -1):

i done it use following code

```
$names = array('fred', 'bob', 'john');

$input = array('bob' => array('bob data'), 'john' => array('john data'), 'fred' => array('fred data'));

$result = [];
foreach ($names as $name) {
    $result[$name] = $input[$name];
}
print_r($result);
```

Comment: The least you could do is to upvote my answer before using it inside your own; this is not [the first time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24282545/php-multi-array-foreach-loop/24283158#24283158) you've done this, either.